# How do I paste from the clipboard into a Python window?

Tags: python, paste

How can I paste something from the clipboard onto a Python window. I press `Ctrl-V` and it doesn't work. I click the right button of my mouse and nothing happens. Do I need to install something? I have Python 2.7.11 on Windows 7.

Comment: What are you using for that Window? Tkinter? PyQT? Something else?

Comment: What is a "python window" supposed to be? Copying and pasting doesn't have anything to do with Python but with your editor or shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to copy something from the python console: Highlight what you want to copy and right click on the top border of the python console>edit>copy

If you want to paste into python console window:
Make sure the coping mentioned above is the last action taken, and you will be able to simply right click I'm the python console window black area and it will automatically paste. You can also right click on the top border and follow the >edit>paste menu item.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know you had to right click on the top border. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

in the above at the left most portion there is present python symbol, go and right click to that python symbol, you will found "edit" option is there. click edit and you will gate PASTE.

Answer (score 0):

In pythonic way, We can use `pandas` library to paste clipboard.

```
import pandas as pd
copied_data = pd.read_clipboard() #clipboard data saved in variable copied_data
```

Answer (score 0):

try using magic commands %paste or %cpaste above the copied line of code. This will prevent any unexpected errors. Use % for line magic and %% for cell magic.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on Python Text widgets. On **OS X**, that would be <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

If you want to do this programmatically - you can use the [clibpoard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipboard/0.0.4) package from PyPi.